# Jenkins - translate withCredentials into declarative style syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline which is written using a scripted syntax and I need to make this into a new pipeline using a declarative style.

This is my fist project with jenkins and I am stuck at how to translate the withCredentials syntax in declarative jenkins.

The original(scripted) pipeline looks something like this:

```
stage('stage1') {
     steps {
        script {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: CredentialsAWS, passwordVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', usernameVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')]) {
                parallel (
                    something: {
                         sh 'some commands where there is no reference to the above credentials'
                    }
                )
            }
        }
     }
}
```

So far, I have set the credentials in question as an environment variable but since in the original pipeline these are not referenced in the command but they just wrap around the command as 'withCredentials', I am not sure how to achieve the same result. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you find any solution? can you please share any solution?

Comment: Hi @DarrylRN, the answer below by Dmitriy Tarasevich is what worked for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all take a look at [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment)

For your case pipeline will look like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment { 
        YOUR_CRED = credentials('CredentialsAWS') 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Call username and password from YOUR_CRED') {
            steps {
                echo "To call username use ${YOUR_CRED_USR}"
                echo "To call password use ${YOUR_CRED_PSW}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
   pipeline {
      agent any
        parameters {
string(name: 'STATEMENT', defaultValue: 'hello; ls /', description: 'What should I say?')
 }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
     steps {
    /* CORRECT */
    sh('echo ${STATEMENT}')
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

[visit here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!