# withCredentials() block jenkinsfile syntax error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

The `withCredentials` block syntax is confusing me. I have tried placing it outside `stages{}`, outside stage('saving stross...'), and now within the stage('saving stross...'), but I am unable to fix this syntax error in the `jenkins pipeline`.

**jenkinsfile:**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'node1'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('saving stross token and printing') {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'devadrita-stross', variable: 'deva-stross')]) {
                steps {
                    script {
                        bat """
                        python -u C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//stross//stross-script.py, token = "${deva-stross}"
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**error-**

```
Started by user admin
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: Unknown stage section "withCredentials". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 8, column 9.
           stage('saving stross token and printing') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 8: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "saving stross token and printing" @ line 8, column 9.
           stage('saving stross token and printing') {
           ^
```

Comment: `withCredentials` must be inside of `steps {}`. Alternatively use `credentials()` in `environment` block, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235155/7571258

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node { label 'node1' }
  }
  stages {
    stage('saving stross token and printing') {
      steps {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'devadrita-stross', variable: 'deva-stross')]) {
          script {
            // is not safe
            bat """
              python -u C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//stross//stross-script.py, token = "${deva-stross}"
            """
            // https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/
            // bat '''
            //   python -u C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//stross//stross-script.py, token = $deva-stross
            // '''
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```