# Jenkins pipeline - optional credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I have a pipeline that is taking some credentials as a parameter.

```
credentials(name: 'API_TOKEN', description: 'API Access Token', defaultValue: null, credentialType: "org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl")
```

Later in environment section I'm using it like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        MY_TOKEN = credentials('API_TOKEN')
    }
```

And later I refer to MY_TOKEN in a pipeline.

My problem is that if this job is started automatically by Jenkins after git commit (without any credentials passed) or if you decide to run a job without credentials at all the job cannot start (instant fail). I tried to set defaultValue to "dummy" but `credentials('dummy')` throws a similar error like `credentials(null)`.

I tried to give up on setting an additionall variable in an evironment section and refer directly to API_TOKEN but it doesn't help as in that case a manually given parameter is not being respected and a default value is being used instead (null or 'dummy').

How to properly implement optional credentials in a pipeline?

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by setting environment section as a part of a stage with condition to only run if API_TOKEN is set. If API_TOKEN is not set, the whole stage is not running and we are not reaching credentials() method. Also I needed to replace credentials('API_TOKEN') with credentials('${API_TOKEN}') for some reason for binding to work. I still consider it as a workaround so I'm not closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

As per Jenkins documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters), I don't see `credentials` as an option for parameters. However, from Jenkins GUI editing a pipeline configuration, `credentials` parameter is indeed available.

Taking a look at the options from the credentials parameters in the GUI, I see that it refers to stored credentials in Jenkins Credentials Provider. Knowing this, my suggestion would be to add a string parameter that refers to the credential ID of the stored credential. Something like this:

```
string(name: 'TOKEN_CRED_ID', defaultValue:'', description: 'Credential ID to API Access Token')
```

Then, in your pipeline logic, handle the event of having an empty string as your `TOKEN_CRED_ID` like so:

```
String credId = params.TOKEN_CRED_ID.trim();
if(credId) {
   withCredentials([string(credentialsId: credId, variable: 'apiToken')]) {
      // Use 'apiToken' here
   }
} else {
   // Manage the case where no credential ID is provided
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that way when you click "Build with parameters" you will see a string form instead of "pick your credentials from a store" form what also sucks. Btw. your answer with "withCredentials" doesn't apply to declarative syntax (following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232192/jenkins-translate-withcredentials-into-declarative-style-syntax)

Comment: @aerion Ah ok! I didn't know you wanted a dropdown with available credentials in Jenkins GUI. However, I've used my proposed solution in a declarative pipeline and it works with `withCredentials`. In my case, the jobs were started via an external tool (not Jenkins GUI) so the string option was adequate for our needs.